# Why does this compile with MSVC C++17, but fails with MSVC C++20?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

MCVE:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Json;
class Json_iterator;
class Json_reverse_iterator;
class Json_const_iterator;
class Json_const_reverse_iterator;

class Json_iterator
{
    std::map<std::string, Json>::iterator               objectIter_;
};

class Json_reverse_iterator
{
    std::map<std::string, Json>::reverse_iterator       objectIter_;
};

class Json_const_iterator
{
    std::map<std::string, Json>::const_iterator         objectIter_;
};

class Json_const_reverse_iterator
{
    std::map<std::string, Json>::const_reverse_iterator objectIter_;
};

class Json final
{
public:
    Json &Get(std::string const &key)
    {
        auto const it = object_.find(key);
        return it->second;
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, Json>     object_;
};

int main()
{
    Json json;
    Json child = json.Get("foo");

    return 0;
}
```

I have trimmed this down to the absolute bare minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.  This is what remains of my own "header only" Json library, together with a minimal `main()` to demonstrate the problem.  If the sample is compiled with MSVC in C++17 mode, there are no errors.  Switch to C++20 mode using VS 2022, and the `return` statement in `Json::Get()` generates the following error:

```
error C2079: 'std::pair<const std::string,Json>::second' uses undefined class 'Json'
```

What is weird is that under C++20, if the four declarations of `objectIter_` in the four iterators are removed, it also compiles correctly.  While this is an interesting data point, it's not a viable solution, since the `objectIter_` members are necessary to make the iterator work in the first place.

So what got changed in the transition from C++17 to C++20, and what options do I have to fix this?

Comment: You are using `std::map` with incomplete type `Json`. I feel your issue is caused by addition of conditionally explicit constructors to `std::pair` in C++20. The code probably applies `std::is_constructible_v` or similar to template argument and using those with incomplete types is undefined. MSVC doesn't handle this well at all, but GCC gives much better error description.

Comment: [Happens for GCC too](https://godbolt.org/z/bT6Eazrrf).

Comment: @StaceyGirl So this will probably never compile as is under C++20.  I can think of two possible solutions:  1. Switch to a `std::map<std::string, Json*>`, use `new` to allocate them and then add logic to `Json::~Json()` to clean up; or 2. Switch from a header only library to a compiled `.LIB` and just always compile that with C++17.

Comment: @dgnuff You can still put the implementation at the bottom of the header, outside of the class, if you mark it `inline`. If possible, at that point `Json` is complete.

Comment: @Quimby  That didn't work, at least what I tried didn't.  Moving `Get()` outside doesn't solve the problem, it's the actual declaration of `object_` itself that's the issue, that has to stay inside `class Json`.  I'm starting to get traction with a `class JsonPtr` that's nothing other than a wrapper for a `Json *`.  Not pretty, and it'll probably impact performance, but it does compile without complaint under C++20

Comment: @dgnuff I meant why not something like this https://godbolt.org/z/dc3b6nsnv ?

Comment: @Quimby  That can be made to work, although it'll be a bit of effort.  Iterators are more complex than in the MCVE shows.  Specifically, `class Json` has both a `std::map` for objects, and a `std::vector` for arrays, and Iterators have to have the smarts to handle either type.  https://godbolt.org/z/45nGaeWc4 gives some idea of what's really happening.    I only needed objects to show the issue, so I trimmed all the array logic out. :)

Comment: @dgnuff Oh, yea I have no doubt it is more complicated than it looks, I'm just saying there might be a way how to do that without resorting to `new` and pointers. Good luck I guess :D

Comment: @dgnuff BTW someone asked about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343631/stdmapreverse-iterator-doesnt-work-with-c20-when-used-with-incomplete-typ), surely based on your question. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can provide an easier solution.

Comment: I ought to file a compiler bug with MSVC, since now that I fully understand the issue, despite what MSVC was claiming, the error has nothing to do with `Json::Get()`.  The `std::map`s that are responsible are the ones in the Iterators, which explains why moving them below `class Json` does indeed provide a solution.