# std::map::reverse_iterator doesn't work with C++20 when used with incomplete type

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, stdmap, reverse-iterator

I noticed that the use of `std::map::reverse_iterator` in the below example doesn't work with C++20 but works with C++17 in all compilers.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jYq1q3EKE)

[Demo MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/d3Td69hKK)

```
#include <map>
class C; //incomplete type 

class Something
{
    
    //THIS WORKS IN C++17 as well as C++20 in all compilers
    std::map<int, C>::iterator obj1;
    
    //THIS DOESN'T WORK in C++20 in all compilers but works in C++17 in all compilers
    std::map<int, C>::reverse_iterator  obj2;
};

int main()
{
    Something s;
    return 0;
}
```

**My question is** what changed in `C++20` so(such) that the use of `std::map::reverse_iterator` stopped working in all `C++20` compilers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works by chance pre-C++20, by standard it's UB to use incomplete types in std containers (with the exception of `vector`, `list` and `forward_list` since C++17). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12295799/4885321). Thus, it may work and may stop working at any time, but basically anything can happen and it should not be relied on.

If being able to store an incomplete type is a hard requirement for your use case, you may want to check [`boost::container`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html).