# vector of variants with forward declaration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++17, visual-studio-2022

I would like to understand why, using Visual Studio 2019 or 2022, the following code compiles with the `a` and `b` variables but not with the `c` variable. Is there any workaround for this issue?

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct data; // defined in another file

std::variant<data>* a; // ok
std::vector<data*>  b; // ok

std::vector<std::variant<data>*> c; // error C2139: 'data': an undefined class
                                    // is not allowed as an argument to 
                                    // compiler intrinsic type trait 
                                    // '__is_trivially_destructible'
```

The complete error message is:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(931,60): error C2139: 'data': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_trivially_destructible'
1>C:\Temp\test2019\main.cpp(4): message : see declaration of 'data'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(931): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::is_trivially_destructible<data> >' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(1006): message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::_Variant_destroy_layer<data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector(1667): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::variant<data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector(1665): message : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<std::variant<data> *,std::allocator<std::variant<data> *>>::_Destroy(std::variant<data> **,std::variant<data> **)'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector(1751): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<std::variant<data> *,std::allocator<std::variant<data> *>>::_Destroy(std::variant<data> **,std::variant<data> **)' being compiled
1>C:\Temp\test2019\main.cpp(8): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::variant<data> *,std::allocator<std::variant<data> *>>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(60,19): error C2139: 'data': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_constructible'
1>C:\Temp\test2019\main.cpp(4): message : see declaration of 'data'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(60): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::is_move_constructible<data>,std::negation<std::conjunction<std::is_trivially_move_constructible<data> > > >' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(97): message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::_SMF_control_move<std::_Variant_destroy_layer_<data>,data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(39,19): error C2139: 'data': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_constructible'
1>C:\Temp\test2019\main.cpp(4): message : see declaration of 'data'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(39): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::is_copy_constructible<data>,std::negation<std::conjunction<std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<data> > > >' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(61): message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::_SMF_control_copy<std::_Variant_destroy_layer_<data>,data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(462,32): error C2079: 'std::_Variant_storage_<false,data>::_Head' uses undefined struct 'data'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(810): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Variant_storage_<false,data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(916): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Variant_base<data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(82): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Variant_destroy_layer_<data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h(120): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Variant_destroy_layer_<data>,data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(1006): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Variant_destroy_layer_<data>,data>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(1008,86): error C2139: 'data': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_destructible'
1>C:\Temp\test2019\main.cpp(4): message : see declaration of 'data'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(1008): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::is_object<data>,std::negation<std::is_array<data> >,std::is_destructible<data> >' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\variant(1008,19): error C2338: variant<Types...> requires all of the Types to meet the Cpp17Destructible requirements N4828 [variant.variant]/2.
```

Comment: Because [prior to C++20, it is undefined behavior to use incomplete types in `std` containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73343983/12002570) (with some exceptions). Also see [The standard requires that, all types used in template components of the standard library must be complete, unless otherwise stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12295799/12002570).